# Seeking Louisiana PLSS GIS data - Converting (Township Range & Section) to Lat Long coordinates in 2018

Tags: plss

I have seen this question asked before for other US States, but based upon my understanding of [Public Land Survey System](https://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/a_plss.html), each State has its own reference grid. It appears that the US Government once provided a [webservice conversion tool called "Geocommunicator"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182957/convert-plss-section-township-range-meridian-to-latitude-and-longitude-usin), but this is now offline, denigrated, or no longer supported. Is this BLM document of [State PLSS geodatabases](https://nationalcad.org/download/PLSS-CadNSDI-Data-Set-Availability.pdf) meant to be a replacement?

To be specific, I need to convert the Township Range Section boundary information for two properties to Lat Long in the State of Louisiana. These properties are in the swamp and are not accessible by road.

Comment: Perhaps [this dataset](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/public-land-survey-system-of-louisiana-geographic-nad83-usgs-2003-plss-la-usgs-2003) could be of help. You can display the shapefile in Google Earth and get the lat/long there.

Comment: I've actually looked at that dataset before on the US Open Data portal, but the quality of that State PLSS dataset is low, and doesn't include the Section info which is in the PLSS geodatabase linked to in my original post.

Comment: The TRS data available from BLM Navigator or NationalCad is already in lat long Nad83.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Bureau of Land Management document](https://nationalcad.org/download/PLSS-CadNSDI-Data-Set-Availability.pdf) lists the best GIS data available on a state-by-state basis for PLSS (Public Land Survey System) Cadastral survey resources. It seems that data materials are maintained or updated by a variety of authors, but most or all are vetted by the FGDC Cadastral Subcommittee chaired by the BLM.

There is also a [BLM ArcGIS Online map server](https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastral/BLM_Natl_PLSS_CadNSDI/MapServer) which seems to have replaced the Geocommunicator web service (now offline)